# nginx does not close socket

Tags: nginx, socket

ngnix is not closing the socket after the connection finishes.  I've googled and can't come up with anything to will tell nginx to close this connection, other than what I have below: `keepalive_timeout 0`.

In both the request and response headers, I can see `Connection: close`, but the socket still sits around in the `TIME_WAIT` state for about a minute.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:40345         TIME_WAIT   -
```

Here are the headers:

```
Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2011 15:34:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
```

Part of my nginx config:

nginx config file:

```
{
...
        keepalive_timeout 0;
        client_max_body_size 1M;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 60;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fastcgi.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files not found
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Waiting in TIME_WAIT state for few minutes is by design, 
please check following links for full description:

http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2941  http://www.ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/tcpTutorialNotes.html